# Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException

Tags: azure, rest, unhandled-exception

I received this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The client
> 'XXX' with object id 'XXX' does not have authorization to perform
> action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over
> scope '/subscriptions/YYY/resourcegroups/FluentRG' or the scope is
> invalid.
> If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I have logged in my Azure Account into VS Code, and I have granted permission to my email address as a contributor in my current subscription. Still, this exception is seen.

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;

    namespace RESTApp
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var azure = Azure.Authenticate("Azure-authentication.txt").WithDefaultSubscription();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating a new VM...");

                var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define("VMCreatedWithFluent")
                    .WithRegion("West Europe")
                    .WithNewResourceGroup("FluentRG")
                    .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
                    .WithPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
                    .WithNewPrimaryPublicIPAddress("fluentdns")
              .WithPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.WindowsServer2012Datacenter)
                    .WithAdminUsername("serverAdmin")
                    .WithAdminPassword("mySuperSecurePassword18")
                    .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardDS3V2)
                    .Create();

                Console.WriteLine("Successfully created a new VM: {0}!", windowsVM.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you confirmed that client ID 'XXX' is an Azure AD principal associated with your email address (and not, for example, an application service principal)? You can confirm this a number of ways, but the easiest may be the Azure Portal and finding your user in Azure AD. If it is you, confirm there are no Policies or Locks on the resource group which may be denying your action.

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Joy! Your reply helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [blog](http://www.jamesgriff.in/index.php/2018/02/04/one-api-to-rule-them-all-the-fluent-management-api/) that you suppose to refer to(as the code is the same as yours and also uses `Azure-authentication.txt` to auth).

In this blog, it uses the service principal credentials in `Azure-authentication.txt` to auth, not your logged user account, to solve the issue, you need to assign an RBAC role to your service principal, just follow the step `Setting up a Service Principal` in the [blog](http://www.jamesgriff.in/index.php/2018/02/04/one-api-to-rule-them-all-the-fluent-management-api/).

You can also do it in the portal, if you follow this blog exactly, the service principal is named `FluentAPIApp`, just navigate to the subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> search for its name and assign a `Contributor` to it like below.

[image]